# Having C structure same need to implement in python and call from different .py file

Tags: python, tkinter

I trying to write structure in Python (don't get any more information in online), which is defined in one .py file. I need to import .py and take the information of structure and do logic check.

Existing C structure is as below:

```
typedef struct
{
U16   ID;
S8    Name[32];
S8    Description[96];
S8    Units[16];
enum  eType Type;
F32   Scaling;
F32   Offset;
BOOL  Writeable;  
}sDataInfo;

/* ID's,       Name,                 Description,                    Unit,   Type,  Scaling,  Offset, Writable */

sDataInfo data_items[] =
{
  0x0202, "dtc_num_of_faults_",     "Number of DTCs",               "",        u8,     1,           0,       FALSE, 
  0x2007, "FlBodyVertLocSel_A_Meas_", "FL Vertical Acceleration", "m/s^2", s16,    0.05,        0,       FALSE, 
  0x2008, "FrBodyVertLocSel_A_Meas_", "FR Vertical Acceleration", "m/s^2", s16,    0.05,        0,       FALSE,  
  0x2022, "RlBodyVertLocSel_A_Meas_", "RL Vertical Acceleration","m/s^2",   s16,   0.05,        0,       FALSE
}
```

which is the best way to define the structure in python,it will be help full some more clear answer with sample code.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Are you trying to call a C code from Python?

Comment: No. I want to create  python  structure similar  like C code as shown above. Structure definition in one python file and I need to call the structure in another file, to do matching

Comment: Do you want to make an actual C compatible structure, or do you just want a similar datatype? If the former, check out ctypes, if the latter just use a Python dictionary or a class.

Comment: I just want similar datatype. What do you suggest Python dictionary or class, it should be easy to import structure to another python file.

Comment: Just use a class, that's flexible and easy to import.

Comment: Can you give me reference to python struct or any simple example is appreciated

Comment: Can you tell me how to write above Code

Comment: There are plenty of class examples around, e.g. https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2014/06/18/improve-your-python-python-classes-and-object-oriented-programming/